# Pytest - send image in nested object

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-django

I've got an endpoint that receives a form data, where one of the keys is an array of objects that contain an image.

I'm trying to make the following test for the endpoint

```
file_horizontal = BytesIO()
image_horizontal = Image.new('RGBA', size=(244, 100), color=(155, 0, 0))
image_horizontal.save(file_horizontal, 'png')
file_horizontal.name = 'teste_horizontal.png'
file_horizontal.seek(0)

file_vertical = BytesIO()
image_vertical = Image.new('RGBA', size=(138, 100), color=(155, 0, 0))
image_vertical.save(file_vertical, 'png')
file_vertical.name = 'teste_vertical.png'
file_vertical.seek(0)

self.data = {
    'part_id': 123
    'logo': [
        {
            'logo_type': 'HORIZONTAL',
            'document_type': [1, 2],
            'image': file_horizontal
        },
        {
            'logo_type': 'VERTICAL',
            'document_type': [3, 4],
            'image': file_vertical
        },
    ]
}

def test_diff_create(self):
    response = self.client.post(self.url_create, self.data, format='multipart', HTTP_ACCEPT='application/json; version=1.0')

    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

This way, the endpoint receives the logo data as  `"{'logo_type': 'VERTICAL', 'document_type': [3, 4], 'image': <_io.BytesIO object at 0x7fc4deadf8b0>}"`

The logo data is not sent as an array, and it only sends the last object of the array. In json format, the data is sent as an array, but I can not send the images in json because they are not json serializable.

The endpoint expects to receive an array like this

```
[{'logo_type': 'HORIZONTAL', 'document_type': [1, 2], 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test_horizontal.png (image/png)>}, {'logo_type': 'VERTICAL', 'document_type': [3, 4], 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test_vertical.png (image/png)>}]
```

Comment: you need to read file content and pass a bytestring (serializable), not a file handler object (not)

Comment: @Marat I tried passing like `file_horizontal.read()`, but the endpoint received the data as `"{'logo_type': 'VERTICAL', 'document_type': [3, 4], 'image': b'\\x89PNG\\r\\n\\x1a..."`

Comment: You could convert image into base64 encoded string which is json serializable

Comment: @dropnz I tried a base64 string, but it needs to be a file, otherwise the serializer throws the error `rest_framework.exceptions.ValidationError: {'logo': [{'image': [ErrorDetail(string='The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')]}, {'image': [ErrorDetail(string='The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form.', code='invalid')]}]}`.

Comment: This is what I'd expect it is supposed to receive. Did it work? If not, what does the endpoint expect in this field?

Comment: @Marat The endpoint expects to receive an array like this `[{'logo_type': 'HORIZONTAL', 'document_type': [1, 2], 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test_horizontal.png (image/png)>}, {'logo_type': 'VERTICAL', 'document_type': [3, 4], 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: test_vertical.png (image/png)>}]`

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade Something is missing here. How is `<InMemoryUploadedFile: test_horizontal.png (image/png)>` (an object instance) derived from the payload?

Comment: If I do `self.data = {'logo': file_horizontal}` with json format in the test, the endpoint receives `{logo: <InMemoryUploadedFile: test_horizontal.png (image/png)>`. It just needs to be file, it can not be a string.

Comment: I've did some research, I don't think it is possible to send a nested object in form data format. A solution is to send the images as base64 in json format.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile
from six import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

    image = BytesIO()
    Image.new('RGB', (100, 100)).save(image, 'JPEG')
    image.seek(0)
    self.image_1 = SimpleUploadedFile('image.JPG', image.getvalue())
```

Now it's up to you use it in setup method or every single test function
it working fine for django Version: 3.2.7